# Removing named HTML entities in strings

Tags: c#

I would like to remove named html entities and replace them with their numeric equivalents. HtmlDecode unfortunately removes both. Is there a way of just removing the named ones?

```
var cats = "<div>&#160;</div> <p>&#65279;&beta;</p>";
cats = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(cats);
```

I would like this output

```
<div>&#160;</div> <p>&#65279;&#914;</p>
```

Comment: @CodeCaster: if the OP decode then encode, it will leads to `&lt;div%gt; ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to find the named HTML entities, decode them, and then create the numeric equivalent:

```
cats = Regex.Replace(cats, @"(&[A-Za-z]+;)", m => {
  return "&#" + ((int)HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(m.Value)[0]) + ";";
});
```

---

If you want to ignore entities that aren't valid, you would decode them and then check if they changed, so that you can just leave them if they don't:

```
cats = Regex.Replace(cats, @"(&[A-Za-z]+;)", m => {
  string decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(m.Value);
  return decoded != m.Value ? "&#" + ((int)decoded[0]) + ";" : m.Value;
});
```